# perform zoom on NOT opened APRX

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, pdf, zoom

I was planning to write a script which would save a copy of aprx from the template and perform the zoom on all Layouts. Just to simplify things I will give an example of one Layout. On Layout called Elevation, zoom should be performed to Site Boundary (always different size, geometry, and location). See below what I have prepared, but it is not performing the zoom.  I think I don't call correctly newly created aprx, but I can not figure out where is the issue. If I create and aprx and run the zoom on the opened aprx (using "CURRENT") it works very well, but I woulld like to do the same without needing to open it.

```
import arcpy, os  
import math  
def path_file(path):  
    path_split = path.split(os.sep)  
site_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  
out_path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (1)  
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\.....\Template.aprx")  
aprx.saveACopy(out_path + os.sep + site_name + ".aprx")  
new_aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(out_path + os.sep + site_name + ".aprx")  
m = aprx.listMaps("Elevation")[0]  
lyr = m.listLayers("Site Boundary")[0]  
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("Elevation")[0]  
mf = lyt.listElements("mapframe_element", "Map" )[0]  
mf.camera.setExtent(mf.getLayerExtent(lyr, False, True ))  
if mf.camera.scale < 1000:   
   mf.camera.scale = 1000  
else: mf.camera.scale = mf.camera.scale * 1.15  
mf.camera.scale = math.ceil(mf.camera.scale/2000)*2000
```

Comment: I tried to answer this, but your code is too confusing. You're making a copy of an APRX, never using it, and then you have a loop that finds all APRX in a directory and exports them. Based on the code, I don't see how there would ever be more than 1 APRX, so why the loop? And the APRX in that directory is a copy of the original which has NOT had a zoom performed on it. If you have multiple APRXs all the zoom code should be happening in the loop. I could re-write this, but how and what should be happening is not clear

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me. You said “You're making a copy of an APRX, never using it,”, I think that is part of the problem of why the script doesn’t do what I had in my mind. I want to create a copy of aprx, perform zooms on all Layouts and them export all pdf. You are right most of the time there would be just 1 aprx. The loop is there in case I save a new aprx later so that all Layouts (even from multiple aprx) get exported. Hope that makes better sense now.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused with what you actually have and what you want to do. Unless someone else here has an idea, I'd suggest updating your problem statement in the post.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am happy for any feedback I am new to arcpy and still learning. So despite of script above (I appreciate it might be confusing)  what I am trying to do 1) save a copy of arpx 2) have zoom performed on newly saved copy 3) export all pdfs. Will try to edit the sentenses so it does make more sense

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems that I can see, for starters:

1. You are creating a copy of the APRX called `new_aprx`, and then you open `new_aprx` but you don't use it for anything.  Instead, you are performing your operations on the previously opened old `aprx` project.
2. You are not saving your changes.  You saved `aprx` as `new_aprx` before making any changes and then opened `new_aprx`.  Then you made some changes (on the old `aprx`, not on the `new_aprx`), but you never save those changes.

To resolve these issue, you need to:

1. Replace occurances of `aprx` with `new_aprx` in each line where it is used AFTER the `new_aprx = ...` line.  In particular, `aprx.ListMaps` with `new_aprx.ListMaps` and replace `aprx.ListLayouts`. with `new_aprx.ListLayouts`.
2. Add a line, `new_aprx.save()` at the end.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. I have followed you suggestion, but it still doesn't seem to  be working. I am sure its becouse I have done something wrong. Could you please send me the whole script please

Comment: Perhaps you should post a new question, with your updated script, and describing the current problem.